# Drawing with request animation framemaximum callstack exceeded?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making my own little canvas library because I have time to kill and am trying to animate my canvas objects, the method currently looks like so;

```
proto.update = function () {


    for (var i = 0; i < this.objects.length; ++i) {

        this.objects[i].draw(this.context);
    }

    var self = this;

    requestAnimationFrame(self.update());
};
```

I have not use `requestAnimationFrame` before and I get an error saying **maximum callstack exceeded**.

I followed this tutorial http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/ and am quite sure I have made no mistakes.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback parameter passed to `requestAnimationFrame` should be a reference to a function to call when it's time for the next repaint (see documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame)). Your error is that you have included parenthesis after the function name which means it executes immediately causing a recursive loop.

Try updating your code as follows:

```
proto.update = function () {


    for (var i = 0; i < this.objects.length; ++i) {

        this.objects[i].draw(this.context);
    }

    var self = this;

    // Pass the function reference don't call it
    requestAnimationFrame(self.update);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing this `requestAnimationFrame(this.run.bind(this));` I don't like transferring `this` when there is a function for it!